# cannot access private member declared in class for make_unique

Tags: c++

I have following classes:  Class A with deleted copy constructor.

```
class A
  {
  public:
    explicit A(int i_a) {a = i_a;};
    ~A(){};
  private:
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
    int a;
  };
```

and Class B with a unique_ptr member.

```
class A;
class B
  {
  public:
    B(int i_b);
    ~B() {};

  private:
    std::unique_ptr<A> p_b;
  };
```

and B.cpp:

```
B::B(int i_b)
  {
  p_b = std::make_unique<A>(A(i_b));
  }
```

I am receiving this error while making unique_ptr of class A:

**'A::A': cannot access private member declared in class 'A'**

Can someone please explain me why I am receiving this error? I know that by commenting this line "A(const A&) = delete;" error will be resolved. But I am looking for some explanation.

Comment: As a side note, it's more typical to declare `delete`d functions as `public` - this way you have clear error message, instead of it being buried under `cannot access private member `. Declaring copy constructors as `private` is an old (pre-C++11) way to disable those, when we couldn't use `delete` keyword.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  p_b = std::make_unique<A>(A(i_b));
```

In this line you are trying to call copy constructor, which you have `delete`d (or move constructor, which is not declared)

Instead, you should use:

```
  p_b = std::make_unique<A>(i_b);
```

Or you could declare move constructors for your class:

```
class A
  {
  public:
    explicit A(int i_a) {a = i_a;};
    A(A&&) = default;
    A& operator=(A&&) = default;
    ~A(){};
  private:
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
    int a;
  };
```

`std::make_unique` will call a constructor of a given class, passing any arguments it has received as they are. So, if you pass an object of type `A`, it will try to use constructor which takes an argument of type `A` - i.e. copy constructor or move constructor.
Because you have declared copy constructor, move constructor was not automatically generated, so it couldn't have been used by `std::make_unique`